# CLI Tab autocomplete does not work for files

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys

**The Issue** -

The autocomplete feature for the command line interface (the terminal on Ubuntu which I open via the hotkey ctrl + alt + T) does not autocomplete file names

**Background** -

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Laptop: Framework laptop
- Arrow keys work fine
- autocomplete works for directory names
- I restart the terminal after each attempted fix
- Relatively new to linux, so beginner mistakes are not outside of my grasp

**Things I have tried** -

- reinstalling bash-completion and uncommenting the bash_completion portion in the `bash.bashrc` file on my machine. I also ensured this file was saved properly.
- Switching shells using the command `chsh -s /bin/bash`

**Closing thoughts** -

I couldn't find any other solutions that seemed relevant to me, so I am looking for other things to try in order to solve this problem.

Comment: Which command exactly are you trying to run - because it depends on the command. Can you run `cat .bash` (in your homedir) - and then press tab twice, and report what happens?

Comment: something like `compgen -f ~/.bash` would also give a good indication of whether completion itself is working (as opposed to a problem with keybindings to the completion functions)

Comment: @ArturMeinild I was trying to install a `.tar.bz2` file as I have done in the past and noticed this time around the autotab completion wasn't working for the file name. I type `ls` in the console, type out some of the file name, and then press tab, but it does not autocomplete, even with almost fully typing out the filename. There are no other similar file names that may be hindering the autocompletion. 

Re: your second request. Could not find `.bash` in my home directory, so I did `cat .bashrc` which printed out the contents of the file. Pressing tab twice did nothing (only a noise)

Comment: @steeldriver output of `compgen -f ~/.bash` looks like : ```/home/akagi/.bash_history
/home/akagi/.bash_logout
/home/akagi/.bashrc
``` (apologies for formatting).  The tab completion did work for autofilling the command however. E.g. I typed `compg` then pressed tab, and it correctly filled in to `compgen`

Comment: @hkj447 please [edit] this new information into your question

Comment: ... as well, please confirm if the issue is with `.tar.bz2` files specifically, the result of `compgen -f *.bz2` in the directory where the file resides, and the output of `echo $FIGNORE` if any

Comment: I have the same problem in Lubuntu 22 Kinetic

Answer (score 1):

```
bind '"\t":menu-complete'
```

add this command end of `~/.bashrc` file  and save it. Then log out and log in again. Now it will work.

For more info check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/40074/ubuntu-terminal-how-do-i-tab-autocomplete-a-filename-window-cmd-stylecycle/40077):